# How can I provide page ranges in \cite?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, numbering, citing

I would like to add page numbers to my references. I have tried the following things:

`\cite[221\psqq]{knuth:ct:a}` for page sequences

`\cite[221\psq]{knuth:ct:a}` for only one page following 221

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error that `\psqq` and `\psq` are undefined control sequences.

How do I make it in the proper way? And how do I correctly reference to a single page?

Comment: This works fine in current `biblatex`.  Have you remembered to load the package?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Upps, I forgot to load the biblatex package. But now I'm getting the error: \bibliographystyle invalid. I'm using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle` is for plain `bibtex`, not `biblatex`. Have a search here for basic `biblatex` usage.

Comment: @PLK Thanks, I have found it. I'm required to use plain bibtex. How can I do the above things (referencing to single page or sequence of pages) in plain bibtex?

Comment: Add `backend=bibtex` to the options of `biblatex` (the default is `backend=biber`).

Comment: @Bernard I have used `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` but still the same error.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: If you are required to use plain bibtex and not biblatex (with or without bibtex as the backend), then you should probably remove the biblatex tag from the question and add the bibtex tag so that the right people can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands `\psq` and `\psqq` are defined by the `biblatex` package. But according to the comments you are not using `biblatex`.

If you cannot switch over to `biblatex` (see [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and linked questions), you can have the "poor man's version" of the commands

```
\newcommand*{\sqspace}{\,}
\newcommand*{\psqstring}{sq.}
\newcommand*{\psqqstring}{sqq.}
\newcommand*{\psq}{\sqspace\psqstring}
\newcommand*{\psqq}{\sqspace\psqqstring}
```

Of course the automatic language switching `biblatex` offers won't work here and you have to modify `\psqstring` and `\psqqstring` manually.

Now you can use `\psq` and `\psqq`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\sqspace}{\,}
\newcommand*{\psqstring}{f.}
\newcommand*{\psqqstring}{ff.}
\newcommand*{\psq}{\sqspace\psqstring}
\newcommand*{\psqq}{\sqspace\psqqstring}

\begin{document}
\cite[12]{bronto} \cite[12\psq]{bronto}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```